# IllegalArgumentException in File Provider - Android 7.0

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

I am trying to access a apk file saved in `Download\AppName\myApk.apk` from my app using `FileProvider` concept but failed

I am using follwing code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        File file = new File(location);     
        // location= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/AppName\MyApk.apk";      
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Login.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALL_APK_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Manifest**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="xxx.xxx.xxx.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
```

**filePath.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <files-path name="adbc" path="Download/AppName" />
</paths>
```

**Exception**

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Download/AppName/MyAPk.apk
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete Java stack trace.

Comment: Note that you added the error message, not the stack trace. It so happens that *this* time, the error message was sufficient. In the future, when you are asking questions on Stack Overflow that involve crashes, post the **entire** stack trace, as the source of your difficulty may lie deeper in that trace than just the top line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
<files-path name="adbc" path="Download/AppName" />
```

with:

```
<external-path name="adbc" path="Download/AppName" />
```